# Simple pass a pointer to another function FAILED

Tags: c

I keep getting RUNTIME ERROR when trying to pass input[i] to another function... I don't know why. It's supposed to pass the address of input[i] to another pointer in the other function so I don't know where it went wrong. It must be something very simple that I failed to catch...

Edit: Actually my program just stop before passing the array and exit.

```
void processInfixExp(const char * fileName)
{
    char ** input = NULL, ** output = NULL;
    int i = 0, numInput = 0;
    char len;
    char tempInput[100] = {0};
    FILE * pFile = NULL;
    if((pFile = fopen(fileName, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot read file %s\n", fileName);
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(fgetc(pFile) == '\n')
        ++numInput;
    /* printf("%d\n", numInput); */
    input = (char**)malloc(numInput * sizeof(char*));
    output = (char**)malloc(numInput * sizeof(char*));
    if(!input || !output)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed.\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }
    rewind(pFile);
    for(i = 0; fgets(tempInput, MAXL, pFile) != NULL; ++i)
    {
        /* printf("%s\n", tempInput); */
        len = strlen(tempInput);
        while(len && tempInput[len-1])
            tempInput[len-1] = '\0';
        input[i] = strdup(tempInput);
        printf("%s\n", input[i]); /* PRINTF SUCCESS */
    }
    fclose(pFile);
    for (i = 0; i < numInput; ++i) 
    {
        convertIntoPost (input[i], &output[i]);
        printf (" input[%2zu]: %-25s  output[%2zu]: %s\n", i, input[i], i, output[i]);
    }
    free(input), free(output);
}
void convertIntoPost(char * in, char ** out) /* TEST PASSING input[] */
{
    printf("%s", in); /* NO SUCCESS */
}
```

Comment: Is it exciting counting the number of consecutive newlines at the start of the file?  You should review the loop: `while(fgetc(pFile) == '\n')
        ++numInput;`  You should also learn to run the debugger, and/or learn how to print key values as you go through a program.  Looking at `numInput` would likely show you the value 0, indicating trouble.  'Tis curious that you show a print for `numInput`, but you don't comment on the result you got.

Comment: `while (len && tempInput[len-1]) tempInput[len-1] = '\0';` is interesting as well.

Comment: This loop is also curious: `while(len && tempInput[len-1])
            tempInput[len-1] = '\0';` — it should probably be an `if` since you don't adjust `len` in the loop, so after the first iteration, the condition must be false.

Comment: As to your crash, `output[i]` is never set to point anywhere specific, so you get weird behaviour or crashing as you access indeterminate memory.  That affects the `printf()` after the call to the function; the function ignores the `&output[i]` argument (the `out` parameter) so that doesn't cause the crash (probably; technically, it is undefined behaviour even passing the uninitialized pointer, but it probably isn't actually a problem).

Comment: WOW! Please teach me you could tell that numInput there would be 0? could you show me where did its value return to 0? Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh yes! the loop was supposed to be like this `while(len && (tempInput[len-1] = '\n'))tempInput[len-1] = '\0';` Thank you! I need to be more careful with the details.

Comment: What's the value of `MAXL`?  I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: Unless your file starts with a number of blank lines, your loop `while (fgetc(pFile) == '\n')` will exit immediately because the first character it reads is not a newline, and `numInput` will still be zero.  Since you test that memory was allocated and (presumably) pass, you must be inflicted with a system that returns a valid, non-null pointer when you `malloc()` zero bytes, but you aren't allowed to use that memory (because there are only zero usable bytes pointed at).

Comment: it's a const char int 256, defined at the top Andrew. I only copied the relevant functions. I'm sorry I didn't make it clear. -----\n----- Thank you Jonathan, I made that mistake on my first program and now I did it again on my 3rd and still wasn't able to catch it.  It's working now, moving on to the next bug!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `convertIntoPost` is expected to assign to `output[i]` by indirecting through the `out` parameter that it receives. If you haven't gotten around to adding that part of it, you still need to initialize the pointer, so that the `printf` in the caller will succeed.

```
void convertIntoPost(char * in, char ** out) /* TEST PASSING input[] */
{
    printf("%s", in); /* NO SUCCESS */
    *out = strdup("");
}
```

Also, before you `free(input)` and `free(output)`, you need to free all the strings that they point to, otherwise they'll be orphaned.

```
for (i = 0; i < numInputs; i++) {
    free(input[i]);
    free(output[i]);
}
free(input);
free(output);
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar! This is very important and I missed it.